# Javascript - classes

Tags: javascript

```
function Person(name) {
    this.name = name;
    return this;
}

var someone = new Person('someone');
console.log(someone.name);

var someoneelse = Person('someoneelse');
console.log(someoneelse.name);
```

It this a good pattern to implement constructor functions (classes). This works fine with both new and without new.

[Update:] I think I got the answer I was looking for. Using this without 'new' would return a global object and a very bad idea (Thanks to the comment by Vohuman "by Without using new, this in the constructor is the global object not an instance of the constructor")

[More Update:] Doing it the right way to take care of new and without new,

```
function Person(name) {
   if (this instanceof Person) {
      this.name = name;
   }
   else {
      return new Person(name);
   }
};
```

Comment: You could always just use ES6 classes with Babel or TypeScript.

Comment: check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646698/what-is-the-new-keyword-in-javascript

Comment: Without using `new`, `this` in the constructor is the global object not an instance of the constructor.

Comment: I need to understand how it works under the hood.

Answer (score 2):

You don't use `this` if you're not going to use the `new` operator.  Instead create a local object, like so:

```
function Person(name) {
    var obj = {}
    obj.name = name;
    return obj;
}

var someoneelse = Person('someoneelse');
console.log(someoneelse.name);
```

This is called a factory function, and I prefer it to using `new`.  To each their own, though.

[Here's a good article on all of this.](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/javascript-factory-functions-vs-constructor-functions-vs-classes-2f22ceddf33e#.3iwh2js4o)

Comment: The second use is not a factory function; it's broken. For a factory function you will need to define your own object and return it.

Comment: Fixed my wording, @torazaburo.  Thank you for noting.

Comment: You generally use the [factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) if there are more than one category of sub-classes or specialized properties. Where the parameter would be used to specify the exact class, which isn't happening in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The keyword 'new' helps to prevent the pollution on global namespace so if you don't want to type new everytime you do this you can have he following code:

```
function Person(name) {
   if(this===window){
     return new Person(name);
   }
   this.name = name;
   return this;
}
```

Comment: I would rather use the following (works in node environment as well), function Person(firstname, lastname) {
    if (this instanceof Person) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }
    else {
        return new Person(firstname, lastname);
    }
};